# WiX Property passthrough not working (sometimes)

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

Using WiX 3.6 I'm trying to create an MSI for silent installation of an in-house product.

One some machines, my installer works fine, but on others the installer fails with an error message indicating the property value hasn't been passed through from the UI phase to the Install phase of the process:

[image]

This error comes from a guard clause in my WiX source:

```
    <Condition Message="The property SERVER must be defined on the commandline. Installation will abort.">
      <![CDATA[Installed or SERVER]]>
    </Condition>
```

**Why is my Guard clause triggering even though I provide the property SERVER on the command line?**

The installation commandline:

```
msiexec /i 'C:\work\Excel.2010(x86).msi' SERVER=fsis-app-server ENVIRONMENT=Production SKIN=Black
```

According to everything I can find by consultation with Professor Google, all I should need is to make my property public (by using all capitals for the name) and to mark it `Secure="yes"`:

```
<Property Id="SERVER"
          Secure="yes"/>
```

I've done this, but it's still not working - any ideas what I've missed?

Other details ...

... my installer is configured to run as a MajorUpgrade every time.

... I'm deploying exclusively to Windows 7. On my machine (which does have this problem), I have Windows Installer. V 5.0.7601.17514

... Most machines upgrade fine, but a handful (<10 out of 200) fail with this error. My machine is one (helpful for troubleshooting). The previous version is NOT listed under *Programs and Features* on this machine.

**Update #1**

Very interesting, reading the logs. My properties (e.g. SERVER) are **not** losing their values as the install progresses.

If I'm reading the log right, it seems my error in being shown by the *previous* MSI, not the one I'm currently running:

> MSI (s) (D8:D0) [13:20:19:213]: Product: FSIS Plugin for Excel 2010 (32 bit) v4.7.1047.0 -- The property SERVER must be defined on the commandline. Installation will abort.

The installer I'm using is v4.8.9999.0, so the old version number is my clue as to what's happening ... though this doesn't match the v4.5.0.0 in my original screenshot.

Looks like I have two jobs ahead of me ...

... napalm the old installer to clean up this machine
... alter the installer to prevent recurrence.

**Update #2**

I've verified that my failure happens on UNinstallation.

```
    <Condition Message="The property SERVER must be defined on the commandline. Installation will abort.">
      <![CDATA[Installed or SERVER]]>
    </Condition>
```

**Why does this guard clause trigger and abort uninstallation?**

I thought the point of having "Installed or" was to allow it to work properly when removing the product.

Comment: A verbose log file is your friend here. It will show you the state of the properties as they change. To get a verbose log file: msiexec /i path\to\your.msi /l*v log.txt